# A figurative meaning of "take no prisoners"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais

> [take no prisoners](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/take-no-prisoners)
>   ​
>   to be very determined and not care about other people's feelings when trying to achieve something

Quel serait un équivalent français de cette locution ? « ne faire aucune concession » par exemple ?

**EDIT**

Some phrases for context:

> It was just an absolutely take-no-prisoners approach.
>
> (In Rock's) Side two opened with the searing power chords of "Flight of the Rat"; another example of the band's new take-no-prisoners hard rock stance, though at nearly eight minutes, it too found room for some
>   extended soloing from Blackmore and Lord.

See also

https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-when-a-person-says-that-they-take-no-prisoners

Comment: *Ne pas faire dans le détail* te satisferait ? C'est dur de donner une réponse sans aucun contexte.

Comment: En effet, « ne faire aucune concession » ([Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/prisoner/604106?q=take+no+prisoners#877450)) est aussi utile.

Comment: Implacable, impitoyable, draconien...

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je ne crois pas que cette expression existe ; il doit y avoir une confusion avec celle-ci, qui m'est familière, qui n'a pas le sens qui convienne, bien qu'elle rime un peu, et que l'on trouve dans le TLFi, alors que « …dans … » n'y est pas : Loc. fig., fam. Ne pas faire le/de détail. Ne pas se préoccuper de chaque élément pris individuellement. ex : Nous avons décidé de ne pas faire de détail. Il y a quatre bistrots autour de la place, nous les prenons tous les quatre bille en tête (GIONO, Gds chemins, 1951, p. 62)

Comment: On peut nuancer selon qu'on exprime le verbe, comme la définition liée en question, ou [l'adjectif](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/take%20no%20prisoners)... d'où l'intérêt d'avoir un contexte.

Comment: @LPH L'expression *ne pas faire dans le détail* existe, il suffit d'ouvrir les yeux (ou les oreilles). Une rapide recherche montre son utilisation il y a une trentaine d'années, une plus approfondie permettrait probablement d'aller bien plus loin.. On peut la rapprocher de la plus ancienne *ne pas faire dans la dentelle*.

Comment: @LPH *Le menu « effacer » ne fait pas dans le détail : il
offre la possibilité brutale de supprimer, soit tous
les objets, soit tous les éclairages, soit l’intégralité
des éléments présents dans l’univers, autrement
dit, c’est la totale.* TILT, décembre 1988.

Comment: @jlliagre Cette expression est de toutes façon synonyme de l'expression (courante de nos jours) « ne pas faire de détail » et donc elle ne convient pas comme traduction.

Comment: @LPH On ne sait pas complètement ce qu'on doit traduire, dimitris n'ayant pas fourni de contexte. On ne peut donc pas présumer que *ne fait pas dans le détail* ne peut pas convenir. Mon propos ne concerne de toute façon pas ce point, mais le commentaire qui doutait de l'existence de cette expression.

Comment: @jlliagre Non, bien au contraire, son contexte est tout à fait clair et confirmé [ici](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+no+prisoners).

Comment: @LPH Tu sembles ignorer la signification du mot  [contexte](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/contexte). Dimitris n'a donné que l'expression anglaise isolée, donc sans contexte, et une définition de son sens. .[belingwaa.com/les dix qualités d'un bon traducteur](https://beelingwa.com/fr/blog/les-10-qualites-dun-bon-traducteur) : *En outre, il doit utiliser la terminologie la plus adéquate en fonction du contexte et du domaine. Par exemple, un terme bien spécifique ne peut se traduire de la même manière dans un texte juridique et dans un texte financier.*

Comment: @jlliagre La définition concernée : Ensemble de circonstances liées, situation où un phénomène apparaît, un événement se produit ; le contexte est celui de l'opposition en général avec des entraves plus ou moins importantes et bien sûr pas celui de l'opposition militaire ; c'est la même chose pour l'expression « ne pas faire de quartier » ; autant que ce contexte général soit concerné, la majorité des cas sont pris en compte et c'est ce que la demande spécifie, le cas général, sans chercher les rares exceptions. Pour information, le lien «belingwaa…» ne fonctionne pas sur ma machine (lien ?).

Comment: @Il y a bien une définition comme je l'ai écrit, mais il n'y a pas de contexte. Belingwaa répondait hier mais plus aujourd'hui. Internet archive n'a pas de sauvegarde de cette page. Elle sera peut-être de nouveau disponible un jour...

Comment: @jlliagre Je m'excuse de ne pas avoir donné un contexte précis. J'ai pensé que la définition de la locution suffit. Je viens d'y ajouter une couple des phrases.

Comment: _Ne pas faire dans le détail_ existe assurément, c'est la seule variante de l'expression que je connaisse, je suis francophone et le français est ma langue maternelle. On ne peut réduire la langue aux locutions contenues dans un dictionnaire, ce serait complètement réducteur.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

« Ne pas faire de quartier » est une forme équivalente ; voici sa définition dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie en même temps que l'information qui se rapporte au nom « quartier »;

> 4. Sans article. Grâce que l'on accorde à un soldat, à un adversaire que l'on a à sa merci et à qui on laisse la vie sauve (vieilli). Demander, donner quartier. Ne s'emploie plus guère que dans l'expression Ne pas faire de quartier, tuer tous ses ennemis, être impitoyable. Le général ordonna à ses troupes de ne faire aucun quartier. Ne faites pas de quartier ! ou, ellipt. et fam., Pas de quartier !

Answer (score 2):

LPH suggestion is a good generic translation of the phrase, but unlike in English, the French expression can't be used as an adjective.

> It was just an absolutely **take-no-prisoners** approach.
>
> - C'était une approche absolument **impitoyable**.

Or, rephrasing to use a French idiom:

> *- Dans leur approche, ils n'ont **pas fait de quartier**.* (LPH)
>
> *- [...] ils n'ont **pas fait dans la dentelle**.*
>
> *- [...] ils n'ont **pas fait dans le détail**.* (suggested by Stéphane)

Your second sentence in context is also using *take-no-prisoners* as an adjective:

> (In Rock's) Side two opened with the searing power chords of "Flight of the Rat"; *another example of the band's new **take-no-prisoners** hard rock stance*, though at nearly eight minutes, it too found room for some extended soloing from Blackmore and Lord.

Here is a way to translate the relevant part:

> *- Un autre exemple de la nouvelle attitude « hard-rock **pur et dur** » du groupe.*

Comment: Je crois toujours qu'il y a une différence assez importante entre « ne pas faire dans la dentelle » et « ne pas faire de quartier » ; de plus le registre est populaire alors que le registre de « to take no prisoners » et « ne pas faire de quartier » est la langue courante. ((Ac.9) Expr. pop. Faire dans la dentelle, avoir le sens des nuances. Ne pas faire dans la dentelle, agir grossièrement, sans finesse.) Il ne s'agit pas vraiment d'action seulement grossière, mais on insiste sur le fait qu'elle est sans considération pour une opposition humaine plus ou moins acceptable (champ 1)

Comment: ou pour une impropriété de la même sorte; cela est répété dans les définitions en anglais ; c'est confirmé par le dictionnaire de Cambridge :  to be very determined and not care about other people's feelings when trying to achieve something. C'est la même chose en français, je pense, et les autres usages ne sont encore une fois que des additions récentes par des gens qui extrapolent et transcendent à tout va ; l'exemple du rock que Dimitri a ajouté en est un et en voilà un autre « I loved the FZ8's take-no-prisoners look, the gold fork and the mini windshield. » que l'on traduit (champ 2)

Comment: « J'ai aimé la **gueule racée**, la fourche dorée et le minuscule saute-vent de la FZ8. ». On est loin de la réalité de l'expression, c'est pratiquement du n'importe quoi. The adjectival use you highlight is however very relevant. (fin)

Comment: @LPH: Ce n'est pas du n'importe quoi, c'est une bonne traduction contextuelle. Pas comme le serait *j'ai aimé l'apparence qui ne fait pas de quartier, la fourche dorée, etc.*

Comment: Je veux dire que c'est l'original qui est du n'importe quoi et que l'on peut continuer ainsi à faire glisser le sens dans toutes sorte de directions et arriver par exemple à des choses comme un « take-no-prisoners check » pour dire de façon extravagante que la somme est importante.

Comment: @LPH Ça n'a rien d'extravagant, c'est ainsi que les langues vivent.

Comment: @jlliagre: Je m'attendais fortement à la forme récente du terme, et je pensais que « dans le détail » avait plus de chances de mieux convenir, mais finalement dans ce cas précis j'aime bien la dentelle, l'opposition avec le hard rock devient humoristique (par contre on notera que ce n'est pas le ton de l'original). Je dirais même que « dans le détail » poserait un problème dans la formulation que tu suggères, ça pourrait être compris comme un reproche concernant un manque de créativité. Il faudrait dire « leur nouvelle approche hard-rock qui ne fait pas dans le détail » pour éviter ça.